# Handling of authentication alerts when navigating from one application to another application using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Currently I'm working with two applications means in first applocation, after clicking on one link it will direct to another website application in new tab and asks for authentication(user name and password). I'm unable to identify the authentication alert and provide the username and password. So its stopping me to navigate another application. Please help me in this.

Comment: Can you please show the alert you're trying to identify, and what code you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show some work? Steps to reproduce would be great. Have a careful read through [ask].

Comment: I have tried with below code:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("USERNAME", "PASSWORD"));

Comment: I'm working with Chrome, unable to identify the alert elements using inspect elements so I tried with Autoit using below code : 



WinWaitActive("Authentication Required","","10")
If WinExists("Authentication Required") Then
Send("username{TAB}")
Send("Password{Enter}")
EndIf'